# Labeling a process to determine its execution status

Tags: powershell

I have a script `D:\Script.ps1` that runs using a shortcut:

```
# The shortcut is located in the startup folder $Env:AppData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Script.lnk

# The object in this shortcut description
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File D:\Script.ps1
```

How can I see in the console that the process `Script` is working? How can I mark this process in script or in shortcut description so that I can see if it is working or has already completed the task and completed the work? I could track the process using an ID `(Get-Process).ID`, but I do not know the ID of my process when starting OS. I can’t Get it's Name easy and Set, as, for example, in Start-Job. I can not distinguish it from other running processes `powershell` via `(Get-Process).ProcessName`, they all have the `ProcessName` of `powershell`. What can I do to distinguish my `powershell` process from other `powershell` running ones? Thanks

Comment: This question could probably be answer in millions of ways - I guess it depends a little on what you are actually trying to achieve. Running `Get-Process -Id $PID` from within D:\Script should get you the actual process though. Another way could be to simply verify the result of the task being run or writing a log file from within the script.

Comment: Enable Process Creation and Process Termination audit categories on the box, look for event 4688/4689 with corresponding Process IDs. If a recent 4688 events exists but no corresponding event id 4689, then you know that process is still running

Comment: Thanks,  ```$PID``` -  yes, as one of the solutions, but it would be great to name the process and define the process by name.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how it matters what the actual process is called as long as you you can make sure you're targeting the desired process and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch from using a batch file as a wrapper or can tolerate another PowerShell script to launch the real script. You can use Start-Process with the `-PassThru` parameter combined with `Wait-Process` to tell you when it's complete.

Something like:

```bsh
$Process = Start-Process -FilePath C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-command .{read-host} -WindowStyle Normal" -passthru 
$Process | Wait-Process
Write-Host "The process has completed."
```

However, if you need to observe the process completely apart from it there are a couple of other approaches I can think of.

Get-Process doesn't return a command line property but the WMI Win32_Process class does.  You can match some aspect of the CommandLine to differentiate & isolate the process running the script of interest.  Something like:

```bsh
Get-CimInstance win32_Process -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '%d:\\script.ps1'"
```

You can use this directly or to get the PID or any other characteristic to further observe with.  You can certainly get more elaborate with the filter.

Note: Typical best practice is to move the filter criteria to the left, but in this case you might think about using a PowerShell | `Where-Object{}`, as performance probably wouldn't be a concern.  It might make it somewhat easier to filter based on CommandLine.  I'd only do that if the existing filter was troublesome.

You can also add the command line column in Task Manager to watch just the same, but without scripting etc...

These aren't exactly eloquent solutions, but let me know if it's helpful.

Comment: thank you. At the moment, I have not found anything better than writing the status of the process to the registry. I added to the ```script``` the commands for writing to the registry both the state of the process and its ID. Yes, this is a rude decision, but effective.